# Shiny does not load RDS object correctly----Warning: Error in predict_sbo_predictor: external pointer is not valid?

Tags: r, shiny

based on the issue described below, I have a two-part question:

**Questions:**

Did I save the 'corpus_train' SBO object correctly for use with the deployed Shiny app?

AND

How do I ensure that Shiny will read the RDS file correctly, allowing the app to fully deploy and provide results?

**Issue description:**
I have created a very basic word-prediction APP for a class that utilizes an [SBO predictor](https://github.com/themonk99/shinyapp_question) object as the source of the prediction results. That SBO file it named "corpus_train" and is listed in the RStudio environment as "external pointer of class 'sbo_predictor'.

The APP works as intended locally. However, when I deploy to Shiny I receive the following log error:
"Warning: Error in predict_sbo_predictor: external pointer is not valid"

Here is the process I used to deploy to Shiny:
To avoid uploading the very large raw txt files, of which the 'corpus_train' predictor is a subset, I did the following:

1. saved the "corpus_train" with this code: saveRDS(corpus_train, file = "corpus_train_app.RDS")
2. added this code to the global.R file: corpus_train <- readRDS("./corpus_train_app.RDS")
3. uploaded the RDS file along with the global.R, server.R and ui.R files.

I have included the Shiny code below. And, [created a github](https://github.com/themonk99/shinyapp_question) to house the raw files and all other files including the  "corpus_train_app.RDS" file.

global.R code

```
library(sbo) library(shiny) corpus_train <- readRDS("./corpus_train_app.RDS")
```

server.R code

```
shinyserver <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$result_output <-renderText({
            predict(corpus_train,input$text)
    })
```

}

ui.R code

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    
    headerPanel("Predicitve Text APP"),
    sidebarPanel(
            textInput("text", label = h3("Text input"), value = "Enter text..."),
            
            
            
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
            h4("Predicted Words:"),
            verbatimTextOutput("result_output"),

            
            
            h6("This APP generates three predicted next words based on the text you input. 
               The prediction algorithm relies on word frequencies in the English twitter, 
               blogs, and news datasets at:"),
            h6(a("http://www.corpora.heliohost.org/")),
            br(),
            h6("Created May 2021 as part of my Captsone project for the 
            Data Science Specialization provided by Johns Hopkins University and Coursera.
            All code can be located on GitHub at:") ,
            h6(a("https://github.com/themonk99/predictive.git"))
            
    )
```

))

Thank you in advance for your time and feedback! Both are much appreciated-

Answer (score 1):

The issue causing the error "Warning: Error in predict_sbo_predictor: external pointer is not valid?" was two fold and I found the solution here, in the documentation for the SBO package: [SBO package documentation](https://vgherard.github.io/sbo/articles/sbo.html). See the 'Out of Memory' section for further details/examples.

1. The corpus used for predicting the next word should first be created using the sbo_predtable function.

   corpus_train <- sbo_predtable(object = combined_sample_final,
   N = 3,
   dict = target ~ 0.75,
   .preprocess = sbo::preprocess,
   EOS = ".?!:;",
   lambda = 0.4,
   L = 3L,
   filtered = ""
   )
2. Then the sbo.predtable object should be saved as an .rda object

   `save(corpus_train, file = "corpus_train_save.rda"`)
3. Then, on the global.R file, load the .rda file, and then identify the predictor with the sbvo_predictor function.

   `load("corpus_train.rda")`

   `corpus_train <- sbo_predictor(corpus_train)`

The app then deploys without issue.

Comment: I had the very same problem and your instructions saved my day. Thank you!